# How to outline dojo's class code in Aptana?

Tags: javascript, dojo, aptana, outline

I am using aptana3.0.6, I create a class using dojo.declare, such as:

```
dojo.declare("com.a.B", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    b1 : 'b1',
    b2 : function() {

    }
});
```

When i open the outline view, there is nothing in it,it's empty.

What i want is that:
`b1,b2` list in the outline view.

Thanks!

Comment: Try NetBeans, it works fine. IMO it have the best editor for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The current 3.0.x series of Aptana does not support dojo style classes in the outline view.

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/117-configuring-aptana-for-javascript-dojo

Answer (score 0):

IBM worklight (free developer edition) supports the Dojo class outline (and widget palette etc.)

But see my post:

[Class outline of unnamed Dojo declare classes in Worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251526/class-outline-of-unnamed-dojo-declare-classes-in-worklight)

for a problem with unnamed classes.

Greetings,

Daniel van Mil.