# Class outline of unnamed Dojo declare classes in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I use the Worklight IDE to get some nice features such as the Dojo class outline in the outline view that works very nice!

Except: The class outline only works with a named class like:

```
 declare("Myclassname", [ MySuperClass ], 
 {
      ...
 }
```

and this shows a nice outline of the `Myclassname` class.

However, the new Dojo guidelines mention not to use named classes anymore as they pollute the global namespace and the parser now also automatically loads the used modules.
This means the outline cannot be used anymore as it doesn't show the class outline anymore then.

Any ideas on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Myclassname = declare([ MySuperClass ], 
 {
      ...
 }
```

if you are in a require return the Myclassname

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't show a class outline either. When I add a classname to the class the outline is shown nicely. So the only difference seems to be the classname that I don't want to use because of namespace polution. Any more ideas?